# How do I change the Angular JS material input box width

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm usingAngular JS material input box and width of the input box is somewhat small. I want to increase it. Tried lots of solutions as well. But doesn't work. This is my code.

```
  <md-input-container class="md-block">
    <label>Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="address"  ng-model="mgAddress.model.address" value="{{address}}" required/>
    </div>
  </md-input-container>

<md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="$manageAddressController.submitAddress(mgAddress.model.address)" ng-disabled="manageAddressForm.$invalid || manageAddressForm.$pristine">Add</md-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [flex directive](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/children) to make an element either take up a percentage width of the parent or stretch to occupy remaining space.
The element will stretch to fill up the parent container either horizontally or vertically based on if the [parent is a row or a column](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/container)

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex>
    <label>Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="address"  ng-model="mgAddress.model.address" value="{{address}}" required/>
</md-input-container>
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="$manageAddressController.submitAddress(mgAddress.model.address)" ng-disabled="manageAddressForm.$invalid || manageAddressForm.$pristine">Add</md-button>
```

EDIT:

Example from the docs:

```html
<!-- Parent wrapper which specifies the layout as row -->
<div layout="row">
  <!-- Flex directive on the child -->
  <md-input-container class="md-block" flex>
    <label>Company (Disabled)</label>
    <input ng-model="user.company" disabled>
  </md-input-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Nothing changes

Comment: Can you post code with the parent element also shown? The parent must have a `layout="row"` on it for this to work. I would recommend reading up on the [AngularJS Layouts](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/introduction) section to create responsive layouts with ease.

Comment: This is the full code. Above there's normal div and h3..They don't have styles

Comment: Wrapping it in a div might help. The parent must be as wide as you want the child element. Have added an example from the docs to the answer with some annotations for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

you can use css to style the input element. here i have used inline styles as a percentage to set the width of the input box. you can use other metrics(pixels etc..) to set the width too.

```
<md-input-container class="md-block">
 <label>Address</label>
 <input type="text" style="width:120%" name="address" ng-model="mgAddress.model.address" value="{{address}}" required/>
</md-input-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-12" style="padding-right: 700px;" >
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>Address</label>
          <input type="text" name="address"  ng-model="mgAddress.model.address" value="{{address}}" required/>
      </div>
</div>
```

---

you can simply use style="padding-right: 700px;" If you want to set the size of textbox 700px to the right.